# How do I convert convert a unicode list contained in pyspark column of a dataframe into float list?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a dataframe as shown

```
   import ast
   from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
   values = [(u'['2','4','713',10),(u'['12','245']',20),(u'['101','12']',30)]
   df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['list','A'])
   df.show()
   +-----------------+---+
   |             list|  A|
   +-----------------+---+
   |u'['2','4','713']| 10|
   |  u' ['12','245']| 20|
   |  u'['101','12',]| 30|
   +-----------------+---+

**How can I convert the above dataframe such that each element in the list is a float and is within a proper list**
I tried the below one :

   def df_amp_conversion(df_modelamp):
      string_list_to_list = udf(lambda row: ast.literal_eval(str(row)))
      df_modelamp  = df_modelamp.withColumn('float_list',string_list_to_list(col("list")))

   df2 = amp_conversion(df)
```

But the data remains the same without a change.
I dont want convert the dataframe to pandas or use collect as it is memory intensive.
And if possible try to give me an optimal solution.I am using pyspark

Answer (score 2):

That's because you forgot about the type

```
udf(lambda row: ast.literal_eval(str(row)), "array<integer>")
```

Though something like this would be more efficient:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rtrim, ltrim, split 

df = spark.createDataFrame(["""u'[23,4,77,890,4]"""], "string").toDF("list")

df.select(split(
    regexp_replace("list", "^u'\\[|\\]$", ""), ","
).cast("array<integer>").alias("list")).show()

# +-------------------+
# |               list|
# +-------------------+
# |[23, 4, 77, 890, 4]|
# +-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I can create the true result in python 3 with a little change in definition of function `df_amp_conversion`. You didn't return the value of `df_modelamp`! This code works for me properly:

```
import ast
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
values = [(u"['2','4','713']",10),(u"['12','245']",20),(u"['101','12']",30)]

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['list','A'])


def df_amp_conversion(df_modelamp):
    string_list_to_list = udf(lambda row: ast.literal_eval(str(row)))
    df_modelamp  = df_modelamp.withColumn('float_list',string_list_to_list(col("list")))
    return df_modelamp

df2 = df_amp_conversion(df)
df2.show()

#    +---------------+---+-----------+
#    |           list|  A| float_list|
#    +---------------+---+-----------+
#    |['2','4','713']| 10|[2, 4, 713]|
#    |   ['12','245']| 20|  [12, 245]|
#    |   ['101','12']| 30|  [101, 12]|
#    +---------------+---+-----------+
```